# Visa type,embassy for two EU visits (interview and tourism)?

Tags: europe, tourist-visas, business-travel

I have two upcoming visits:

- to attend onsite interview of a company in EU (3 days) in late February
- a tourist visit to EU in early March

The first trip is fully sponsored by the company (flight/hotels/expenses) and they've given me an invitation letter.

I have NOC from current employer, confirmed flight/hotel bookings and other required documents for the second trip.

Comment: How far apart are these visits?

Comment: 25 days between them

Comment: I applied and received a double entry visa from the country of my first visit.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and sharing your experience. But I will convert it to a comment as it is very short as it is.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have three options.

1. Change your itinerary to remain in Europe so you can apply for a single visa.  This may be impractical, of course, as you may not be able to afford it, and you probably have obligations at home between the end of the interview and the beginning of your honeymoon (a wedding, perhaps?).
2. Apply for the more important trip first and ask them as a courtesy to issue a visa that will cover both trips because they are so closely spaced.  If they grant the visa only for the primary trip, you would subsequently have to apply for a second visa for that trip.

   If the most important trip is the interview, then you would apply first to Sweden, but there is perhaps a risk that they would consider France to be the main destination of the two trips, taken together, and refuse to process the application for that reason.  That would cause you to lose time, and time is a bit short here.  It might therefore be safer to apply for the honeymoon visa first and hope they'll include the interview as well.

   This assumes that appointments are equally available.  If one country has appointments available long before the other, then you should apply to that country first.
3. Just forget the whole idea of trying to combine the trips and make two separate applications.  This might be safest, because it will be the least confusing to the visa officer, but you are right to wonder whether you will have enough time.

The application is supposed to be decided within 15 days under normal circumstances, but it can be extended to 30 days or even 60 under exceptional circumstances([Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), Article 23).  So, if you are lucky, you may in fact have time for two applications.